# Android: ListView being overlapped by views below it

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm trying to implement a SlidingMenu that has a "User Profile" at the top and a list of selectable modules below that.

Here is a screenshot of what I have currently:
[image]

This all works as planned but if you notice there is a white gap near the bottom, I've tried everything to get this white bar to get away, I've given the layout beneath the same background color, I've increased the ListView's height to "fill_parent". ANYTHING I change regarding this messes up my entire layout.

Here is a screenshot depicting what goes wrong:
[image]

The view itself doesn't look so bad but the ListView is "gone" or so I originally thought but it still functions normally...

I gave the `RelativeLayout` a slightly transparent background and I can see that the ListView is being overlapped by this Layout.

Please help me figure out why the z-order is changing or to help me figure out the cause of this it's way more frustrating than it needs to be.

**sliding_menu.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000FF">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#ff0">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="168dp"
                        android:background="#f00">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rlProfile"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="8dp" >

                            <com.towbook.mobile.classes.RoundedImageView
                                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                                android:layout_width="55dp"
                                android:layout_height="55dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/square1" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="55dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >


                                <TextView
                                    style="@style/fontSizeTitle"
                                    android:id="@+id/title"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:shadowColor="@color/white"
                                    android:shadowDx="0"
                                    android:shadowDy="-1"
                                    android:shadowRadius="0.5"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:text="Shane Denomme"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    style="@style/fontSizeContent"
                                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:shadowColor="@color/white"
                                    android:shadowDx="0"
                                    android:shadowDy="-1"
                                    android:shadowRadius="0.5"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:text="sdenomme15@gmail.com"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@android:id/list"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/sliding_menu_bg"/>

                    <!-- All your menu options goes here -->

                </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you can replace the RelativeLayout with LinearLayout under the FrameLayout and set ListView match parent. Oh BTW, I do not think you need the Framelayout. You can also place the listView below its subling LinearLayout and set ListView match parent.

Comment: ListView have to be given a fixed height or a parent to match height with. It won't work properly otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the solution to my problem but it did not lie where I first suspected after all. The problem was held in my declaration of the SlidingMenu:

```
    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

    FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFrag = new MenuListFragment();
    t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
    t.commit();
```

Here I am replacing the R.id.menu_frame. This is the wrong id, it should be R.id.left_drawer. as defined here:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF0000FF">
```

This was causing a second listview to be appearing over top of the original listview and this was what was causing it to be overlapped by an empty listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LinearLayout, with layout_height="match_parent", with vertical orientation to solve this

You can set the layout_height of ListView to 0dp and set layout_weight to 1

Then it will try to consume up all remaining space inside the LinearLayout